# If he had known she had too many commitments, he would have done something about it. (Backshifting within the scope of a modally remote preterite)

Tags: past-tense, backshifting

1. If he **knew** she **had** too many commitments, he would do something about
   it.
2. If he **had known** he **had** too many commitments, he would have done
   something about it. (This sentence is made up by myself from the above sentence taken from CaGEL)

What would be the grammatical reasoning behind the second "had" (rather than "had had") in the **second** sentence ("she **had** too many") taking a past form (if correct)?

Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p. 152:

> There are two reasons... why we need to recognize a backshifted preterite as distinct from an ordinary preterite.
>
> (a) Backshifting within the scope of a modally remote preterite
>
> [11]
> **i**  If he knew she *had* too many commitments, he would do
> something about it.
> **ii** I wish he *realised* that she *had* too many commitments.
>
> Example [i] is a remote conditional, with the preterite in *knew*
> expressing modal remoteness, not past time: the time of knowing is
> present. So too (certainly in the salient interpretation, the one we
> are concerned with here) is the time of her having too many
> commitments: it is a matter of knowing in the present about a
> situation obtaining in the present. And the same applies to the *wish*
> construction [ii]. In both, therefore, we have the preterite form
> *had* even though there is no reference at all to past time: this cannot represent the ordinary use of the preterite. Nor would it be
> valid to subsume the preterite in *had* in these examples under the
> modal remoteness use which applies to the matrix clause preterite
> verbs *knew* and *realized*. For clearly the unlikelihood in [i] and
> the counterfactuality in [ii] apply to his knowing/realizing but not
> to her having too many commitments. There is no modal remoteness
> meaning attaching to *had*, for, certainly in [ii], you will in fact
> infer that she does have too many commitments. From a semantic point
> of view, therefore, the preterite carried by *have* must be
> distinguished from that carried by *know* or *realize*, and this
> distinction is reflected in the grammar in that irrealis *were* is not
> suitable for *was* in this construction: If he knew she was/*were too
> busy, he would do something about it; I wish he realized she was/*were
> too busy.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting example of how grammatical analysis and formalism may create a line of reasoning that is more obscure and more complex than the prototype.

The Cambridge account is akin to my describing why we draw our hand back when catching a cricket ball, by using all the specialist terms of energy, force, impact, momentum, friction and interatomic interactions. The simple answer is that it hurts if we don’t.

So it is with this question. We may seek understanding of the subtle combination of the rigorous grammatical concepts or we may seek a simple working view of the two sentence alternatives that you consider. Two rather different problems. I am not competent to undertake the former but view the latter as:

If he knew {*at this present time*} she had {*during the time leading up to and including the present time*} too many commitments, he would {*at this present time*} do something about it.

If he had known {*at some previous time*} she had had {*during the period leading up to and including that time*} too many commitments, he would {*at that time*} have done something about it.

This answer is not to dismiss the importance of grammatical analysis but to distinguish it from the more common pursuit of meaning.

Comment: I understood the past form of the "had" in the first sentence ("If he knew she had too many commitments, he would do something about it") is so neither ①because of the time reference (for time-reference-wise it's supposed to be rather present "has" than past "had") nor ②because of moral remoteness (for this "had" is outside the scope of modal remoteness which applies to the main verb "knew" alone in this case), but ③purely because of formal backshifting, just to be in agreement with the past form of the main verb ("knew," which itself is in this form because of modal remoteness).

Comment: But if you follow this logic, the "had" in the second sentence ("If he had known he *had* too many commitments, he would have done something about it.") should rather be "had had" than just "had" to agree with the past perfect form of the main verb "had known." Or does backshifting only happen with past form and not with past perfect form?

Either way, does "If he had known she had had too many...." sound OK as much as "If he had known she had too many...."? (I'm not even sure if the second one is OK to beging with now.)